# Legends of Eisenwald - where does the game store the savegames?

Tags: windows, legends-of-eisenwald

Does anybody know where the save games of Legends of Eisenwald are stored ?

Answer (score 1):

It's in your user folder, as shown below.

[Steam thread source](http://steamcommunity.com/app/246760/discussions/0/792924952441594353/)

> This is in %localappdata%/Eisenwald (it looks like this usually C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Eisenwald)